# Bootargs format to enable dynamic debug for Linux kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel

I added zynq_remoteproc.dyndbg="func ipi_kick +p" to bootargs variable in uEnv.txt.  On boot, it doesn't get parsed correctly when the module is probed:

```
dynamic_debug:ddebug_add_module: 7 debug prints in module zynq_remoteproc
dynamic_debug:ddebug_dyndbg_module_param_cb: module: zynq_remoteproc dyndbg="func"
dynamic_debug:ddebug_exec_queries: query 0: "func"
dynamic_debug:ddebug_tokenize: split into words: "func"
dynamic_debug:ddebug_parse_flags: bad flag-op f, at start of func
dynamic_debug:ddebug_exec_query: flags parse failed
dynamic_debug:ddebug_exec_queries: processed 1 queries, with 0 matches, 1 errs
```

zynq_remoteproc="+p" does work, but enables every debug in the module.

Enabling from the command line works:

```
echo -n "module zynq_remoteproc func ipi_kick +p" > <debugfs>/dynamic_debug/control
```

What is the proper format to use in bootargs to enable kernel debug statements for just one function?

Answer (score 2):

I know that the question is old, but I haven't come across other answers on the issue.

I can confirm that U-Boot requires a slash. This is a command I used to enable dynamic debug output.

`fw_setenv bootargs_debug dyndbg='\\"file file.c +p\\"'`

I guess that if you manually specify arguments in a *txt* file, the same conditions apply.

Comment: On BBB based custom board I got it working with `dyndbg="\\"file filname.c +p""` other format didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Probably uboot require "\":

```
dyndbg=\"file path/to/you/file.c +p\"
dyndbg=\"file path/to/you/file.c -p\"
dyndbg=\"module module_name1 +p\; module module_name2 +p\"
dyndbg=\"func just_functon_from_kallsyms +p\"
```

module name from lsmod or /usr/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.builtin ('-' changed to '_').